# Triggering builds across different TeamCity instances

Tags: build, triggers, continuous-integration, release, teamcity

We have  multiple groups running their own TeamCity setups inside the firm. My group provides a set of generic libraries that other project groups use in their projects. We use TeamCity to push versions of our libraries to production. What I need is a way to automatically trigger builds on other group's CI system that depend on our libraries once we push a new version to production? I already have have the scripts to upgrade to the latest version etc ready. Right now it is manual, i would like to automate it and have a new build of the dependent projects triggered once we release a version to production. I am looking for a way to push the trigger notification across Teamcity instances.

Comment: There are several checkins that we make to the project, I want those to trigger builds only on my CI instance. I do not want a customer's CI build triggered for every check-in I make. Having said that, i could get my procedure to check in something to a common location and have all customer CI instances have a VCS trigger setup on that particular file. This could be a workaround to trigger chain builds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can trigger TeamCity builds using an HTTP request so you could modify your build script to make the required requests at the end of the build. This does have the downside that you need to hardcode the list of builds that need to be triggered on the remote servers into your build script.

The syntax for the HTTP request is:

```
http://<user name>:<user password>@<server address>/httpAuth/action.html?add2Queue=<build type Id>
```

For full details take a look at this page of the TeamCity documentation:

[Accessing Server by HTTP](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Accessing+Server+by+HTTP)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I had thought of this, but just wanted to know if there is a different way without hard coding. I guess I can do this for now until there is a better option